# Subview position issue after UIOrientation (rotation) change

Tags: iphone, height, rotation, subview, navigationbar

I have a viewController and have added a subview in it programatically.

```
       secondView.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
       [self.view addSubview:secondView];
```

I guess when the device rotates, my mainViewController knows that orientation changed, but the subview (secondView) inside the mainViewController does not know this, so I change its frame to landscape size in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation.

```
       secondView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480 , 260);
```

This does not set in the correct position, it's 11 px below the NavigationBar.
**Why does it start from 11 px below the navigation bar?**

The navigation bar shrinks when we move from portrait to landscape mode and its because of this that my subview is 11px below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change size of the main view (`self.view` I suppose) before. Did you try that?